# EE MSM CE Image path incorrect

Tags: ee2, multi-site-manager, ce-image

I'm using EE 2.9.0 and CE IMG 2.4.5. The primary site has no issues with CE image and the secondary site works great except the secondary site is writing the images to the default site images directory.

```
// main config.php

$config['ce_image_src_regex'] = array(
'^http://cps.domain.org/' => '/chroot/home/siterootfolder/domain.org/html/cps/',
'^http://devwww.domain.org/' => '/chroot/home/siterootfolder/domain.org/html/devwww/'
);

$config['ce_image_document_root'] = '/chroot/home/siterootfolder/domain.org/html/devwww/';

// root index.php on sub-site
$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array(); // This array must be associative
$assign_to_config['global_vars']['ce_image_document_root'] = '     /chroot/home/siterootfolder/domain.org/html/cps/';
```

The file path for the images is outputting, however, being written to the default site. I tried every variation of the above with no avail. Another thing worth mentioning is that these sites are hosted at Nexcess. I tried all the documentation for re: Nexcess. Still no luck.

Comment: You could try adding site specific config changes to each "sites" index.php file since the config.php file is for global changes.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, too. No luck.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of CE Image and looked into troubleshooting this with Jon. We figured out that he had the correct config settings, but that index.php config settings were moved too far down in the index.php file. Moving the files up above the require_once of the EE Bootstrap file solved the problem.